# Accessing another folder content with php

Tags: php, permissions

I have my root folder set to `/var/www/html`, but I have php program that suppose to access/read `Reminder` folder (and its content) which is located in `/home/billing/work/output/Reminder`, scan the folder content (directories, sub-directories, files) and return the file names.

I work on Linux, and I have tried:

```
set_include_path("/home/billing/work/output/Reminder");
include("/home/billing/work/output/Reminder");
```

I have added a symlink in the root to the Reminder folder, but none of this stuff works.
I have a variable:

```
$dir="/home/billing/work/output/Reminder"
```

and when I examine `if is_dir($dir)` I get false.

Can Anyone tell me how can I access the Reminder directory so I can scan the directory?
My user has permissions to Reminder folder, also I have the functions or scanning the folder and they work fine on my local host. Any help will be appreciated, I've been struggling for a week now.

Comment: Don't you need some `""` quote marks around that file path in `$dir = /home.../Reminder`?

Comment: Is your PHP interpreter confined with [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/)? Any of these [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) tools can prevent an application from writing in specific locations, perhaps they aren't yet configured for your site. Check `dmesg(1)` output to see if there are any rejection messages, most or all these tools log to `dmesg(1)` if `auditd(8)` isn't running.

Comment: @sarnold: I forgot to put them in the desription, I have "" in $dir. I also checked dmesg and there are no rejection messages

Comment: Please [edit] the question to reflect reality. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless safe mode and/or open_basedir restrictions are in effect, you should be able to open files from anywhere on the local filesystem.  Just provide the file/directory function you're using with the correct path.

Of course when dealing with the filesystem then you are also dealing with filesystem permissions, so the files and directories you're working with need to be readable by whichever user PHP is running as (If being run by the web server then this will typically be the web server user).

If the above restrictions are in effect, then I'm afraid you're stuck.

Comment: The files/folders have permission to be accessed. Where can I check if the safe mode open_basedir restrictions are in effect?

Comment: Your comment about file permission helped me, I checked file permission to all the folders present in the file path and in one of them my user did not have read permission. Thanks!!!